# What steps do you need to take to translate UIPanGestureRecognizer touches to ScrollView zooming?

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, uigesturerecognizer, cgaffinetransform, uipinchgesturerecognizer

I am creating a gesture recognizer to handle zooming in a scroll view (scrolls along only one on axis at a time). I have the gesture recognizer working but I'm having trouble using the data from the gesture recognizer to transform my views properly. This is what I do right now:

```
- (void)handlePinch:(GPinchGestureRecognizer *)pinchRecognizer
{
 CGSize contentSize = [[self scrollView] contentSize];

 if (pinchRecognizer.pinchType == VerticalPinchZoomIn || pinchRecognizer.pinchType == VerticalPinchZoomOut)
 {

    [[self scrollView] containerView].transform = CGAffineTransformScale([pinchRecognizer transformBeforeTouches], 1, [pinchRecognizer scale]);
    [[self scrollView] setContentSize:CGSizeMake(contentSize.width, [pinchRecognizer initialContentSize].height * [pinchRecognizer scale])];
 }
 ... 
 ...
}
```

This resizes the view nicely, however, it lets it get to strange positions on the screen, and sometimes the scroll view won't be able to scroll all the way to the edge of it (it thinks its boundary is in the middle of the view somewhere and bounces back).

So basically, my question is, what other properties of what other objects and whatnot do I need to operate on to get this working right? View.transform, ScrollView.contentSize, what else? If only Apple's UIScrollView implementation file was open source xD

Answer (score 0):

U do need to add UIPinchGestureRecognizer or neither maintain it.

Just follow [this](http://forums.pragprog.com/forums/83/topics/1488) link to add image in scrollview for zooming